# Adding Events to CompactCalendar CalendarView in android studio (java) from api call

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please I wanted to add events (highlight dates) to a calendar view. I used the default calendar view in android studio but I was not able to achieve it using that so I tried using a different library which was CompactCalendar (https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) everything works well but when I try to add events using the data from an API call it does not work because I cannot update the calendarView with the data. Before you add an Event on the CalendarView,
1. You must first create an instance of an Event (the Event class comes with the library), Here is where you specify the date to highlight
2. You must finally call the addEvent method on the calendarView instance created earlier.

for example, the code below demonstrates how adding events in the library works

```java
Event event = new Event(color, date, data);
calendarView.addEvent(event)
```

This works when I manually create an event using hardcoded dates and call the addEvent method on the calendar. But when I make an API request to my endpoint to fetch the data, I cannot update the calendarView with the data gotten from the onResponse callback from (Google's volley library). Please note that doing some debuggging showed that my data is gotten and no error occurred from the API call, but the calendarView does not update when I call the addEvent method after it has been created. 
Thank You.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. `But when I make an API request to my endpoint to fetch the data, I cannot update the calendarView with the data gotten from the onResponse callback from (Google's volley library).` you should probably include this code as part of your question